# How to create dropdown in MVC using model class and need to display the values(numbers) instead of names?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, asp.net-mvc-5, ado.net

I tried much applications, but no useful. Can any one help me with this case.

For example in dropdown list I have fruits list apple, banana, grape etc ..
If I selected apple in dropdown, then I want to display the value as 1, if banana selected need to display the value is 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a model, you need to create first. Example:

**Model**

```
public class ModelName 
{ 
    public List<SelectListItem> Numbers { get; set; } 
    public int SelectedNumber {get; set;} //add this after your view
}
```

In your **controller**, set this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ModelName();
    model.Numbers = new List<SelectListItem>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        model.Numbers.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() });
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

In your **view** put this:

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedNumber, Model.Numbers)
</div>
```

Then you can access the selected number in your **controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ModelName model)
{
    int selectedNumber = model.SelectedNumber;
    // do anything with selected number
}
```